# set brackets before and after on every hindi word using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set brackets `{` before and after on every words. My code is:

```
string a="अजंडा रस्ता भगा रक्षा hello";
a = Regex.Replace(a, @"\b[^ . ]+\b", @"{$0}");
```

This code is working fine in english words, but if i have hindi words in my textbox this return result like this:

```
{अजंड}ा {रस्त}ा {भग}ा {रक्ष}ा {hello}
```

Why this code split last character from word, and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should use \w instead of [^...].

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Getting same result.

Comment: Try this: @"(\w+)+" - it works in my tests

Comment: @PoulBak I tried but got same result. I tried this code: @"(\w+)+", @"{$0}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use LINQ.

```
string a="अजंडा रस्ता भगा रक्षा hello";
a = string.Join("",from g in a.Split(' ').ToArray() select "{"+g+"}");
```

Comment: Not working. I got output like '{hello}{}'. This code remove all Hindi words.

Comment: I find that.
`a = Regex.Replace(a, @"\b[^ . ]+", @"{$0}");`

Comment: @Masa Your Regex and Linq code is working perfectly. Thanks